# return list of words in dictionary.txt

Tags: python, list, function, file

I'm a beginner to Python. I am begging to learn about functions and files. I need to write a code that will return a list of all the words in `dictionary.txt` using a function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**Current code**

```
def get_dictionary_wordlist(dic):  
     dic = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
     for word in dic:
         return word
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the format of dictionary.txt in your question?

Comment: If you just mean every word separated with spaces, you can try `for word in dic.split():`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a list and add the words there, then you return it.

```
def get_dictionary_wordlist(dic):  
     words = [] # Make a list
     dic = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
     for word in dic:
         words.append() # Add words to the list
     return words
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
dictionary = ('Italy', 'pizza'), ('Germany', 'sauerkraut'), ('Spain', 'paella'), ('USA', 'Hamburger') # Opening the dictionary

def listWords(dic): # Creating the function
    y = dict(dic) # Making sure dic is a dic
    x = [] #creating the list
    for key in dic: # Iterating through every item in dic
        x.append(key) # Adding the item to the end
    return x #returning the results

print listWords(dictionary) #printing the results for the original text, dictionary
```

Comment: can I not open the dictionary within the function?

Comment: you can, but by opening it in the function, it makes it redundant to have a local `(dic)` variable defined by the function, since you redefine it anyway.

Comment: I tried using your method this is what I have:                                              def get_dictionary_wordlist(dic):
    
    words = []
    dic = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    
    for word in dic:
        words.append(word)
        return words
    
    print (get_dictionary_wordlist(dic)) #if i print outside the functions it does not work and if i print within the function nothing is printed...

Comment: I updated the code. I think the problem has to do more with the fact that you're reading the whole text file raw. A raw .txt file has quotes around each line, and /n at the end of every line, which messes up the program. you need to read a single line. What dictionary file are you using?